# incompatibility of Keycloak standalone-ha instances

Tags: keycloak

I have 2 Keycloak 15.0.2 instances on localhost with different ports configured by standalone-ha.xml.
If I make some changes in authentication flows (e.g. coping a flow , add or delete some executions , ...) on a instance, the other instance isn't affected by the changes and remain unchanged.
It also happens when I change a client setting like changing the default browser or direct grant flow in a client

Note that both instances are connected to MariaDB and the database affected by any changes made in any instance.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What is meaning of the term "cluster" in your question? It looks like your "cluster" = Keycloak instance.

Comment: How did you configured your cluster?

Comment: @JanGaraj I mean 2 instances of Keycloak.

Comment: @Abhijeet 2 similar Keycloak instances with --server-config=standalone-ha.xml, similar IP=10.0.0.1 but different in ports (8080 & 8180)

Comment: Finally I solved my problem by deploying the instances with **-Djboss.node.name=... -Djboss.tx.node.id=...**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out that for solving the issue, the Keycloak instances should be deployed by configuring `-Djboss.node.name & -Djboss.tx.node.id`.

For more details, you can check this [link](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/realm-cache-in-standalone-ha-vs-domain-clustered-mode/12675/8)